# Git, OpenSSH, windows 7 "fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly"

Tags: windows, git, server, openssh, sshd

I was not even able to do git push or ferch once. I enter password and its return error:

*"fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly"*

1.) I am login as admin using just password (no ssh keys)
2.) I can connect with ssh with no problems. Can create, delete dirs... whatever...
3.) When try to push by git fatal error appear
4.) I am connecting from same machine for eleminating compatibility or network errors
5.) When use no ssh, just path "d:/git-repos/git-local.git", git working nice

**SSH debug log:**

```
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AUTH_SOCK
debug1: Sending command: powershell git-upload-pack 'd:/git-repos/git-local.git'
debug2: channel 0: request exec confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: exec request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: read<=0 rfd 4 len 0
debug2: channel 0: read failed
debug2: channel 0: chan_shutdown_read (i0 o0 sock -1 wfd 4 efd 6 [write])
debug2: channel 0: input open -> drain
debug2: channel 0: ibuf empty
debug2: channel 0: send eof
debug3: send packet: type 96
debug2: channel 0: input drain -> closed
debug2: channel 0: rcvd ext data 43
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
debug2: channel 0: written 43 to efd 6
debug3: receive packet: type 96
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: channel 0: chan_shutdown_write (i3 o1 sock -1 wfd 5 efd 6 [write])
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 0: almost dead
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 0: send close
debug3: send packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: is dead
debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t4 r0 i3/0 o3/0 e[write]/0 fd -1/-1/6 sock -1 cc -1)

debug3: send packet: type 1
debug3: fd 0 is not O_NONBLOCK
Transferred: sent 2064, received 2528 bytes, in 0.8 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 2580.9, received 3161.1
debug1: Exit status 1
```

**SSH server config:**

```
# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

#HostKey __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
#HostKey __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
SyslogFacility LOCAL0
LogLevel DEBUG3

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

# PubkeyAuthentication yes

# The default is to check both .ssh/authorized_keys and .ssh/authorized_keys2
# but this is overridden so installations will only check .ssh/authorized_keys
AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

# For this to work you will also need host keys in %programData%/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
# PasswordAuthentication yes
# PermitEmptyPasswords no

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
#PermitTTY yes
#PrintMotd yes
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem   sftp    sftp-server.exe

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#   AllowTcpForwarding no
#   PermitTTY no
#   ForceCommand cvs server

#AllowUsers user

Match User user
    ChrootDirectory "D:\git-repos"

Match User supreme
    ChrootDirectory "D:\git-repos"

Match Group administrators
       AuthorizedKeysFile __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys
```

**Seems to fail on command:** `powershell git-receive-pack 'D:/git-repos/git-local.git'`
**When run command from cmd it returns:**
00bdd268299939f6e8bea6ae3e78cf891b59cc79da28 refs/heads/master report-status rep
ort-status-v2 delete-refs side-band-64k quiet atomic ofs-delta object-format=sha
1 agent=git/2.30.0.windows.1

OS: Windows 7 Ultimate SP1 32bit
Using Windows 7 CMD
Git version: 2.30.0 (32bit)
OpenSSH: 8.1p1 for Windows (32bit)

Installed by this guide:
https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/Setting-up-a-Git-server-on-Windows-using-Git-for-Windows-and-Win32_OpenSSH

First I install with no option "Run Git and included Unix tools from the Windows Command Prompt". But I reinstalled it later with this option.

**Env Path server:**

```
%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
C:\ProgramsInstall\OpenSSH-Win32;
C:\ProgramsInstall\Git\cmd;
C:\ProgramsInstall\Git\mingw32\bin;
C:\ProgramsInstall\Git\usr\bin
```

**"SSH where" command output:**

```
C:\ProgramsInstall\OpenSSH-Win32\ssh.exe
C:\ProgramsInstall\Git\usr\bin\ssh.exe
```

**Local repo config:**

```
sshCommand = 'C:\\ProgramsInstall\\OpenSSH-Win32\\ssh.exe' -T -vvv
url = supreme@dev-server:D:/git-repos/git-local.git
uploadpack = powershell git-upload-pack
receivepack = powershell git-receive-pack
```